# Postgres - ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"

Tags: postgresql

I have a function and I need to do different select based on inputid. so I have added the condition as below.

```
....
begin
IF(iv_binrocess = 1 AND IsNull(iv_binno,'') != '') THEN
...//some process here 
END If;
...
End
```

When I run the function, I got the error "

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
>   I referred many sites and tutorials, nothing helped me.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that you have stripped enough code from the sample you posted to strip the problem with it. Please post the complete code surrounding the error. Are you sure that you are looking at the correct `IF` in the function body?

Comment: Show us your **complete** code. **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Also, you added a tag of Postgres, but Postgres does not have `IsNull` function, its equivalent in Postgres is `coalesce` – [see documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

Answer (score 1):

WAG, since you *deleted most of the important information*: You're trying to create a function with a PL/pgsql body, but declaring it `SQL`.

```
craig=> CREATE FUNCTION test() RETURNS void LANGUAGE sql AS 
$$ BEGIN IF TRUE THEN PERFORM 1; END IF; END; $$ ;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: ...TION test() RETURNS void LANGUAGE sql AS $$ BEGIN IF TRUE TH...
```

Declare PL/PgSQL functions as `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.

If you instead want to use an SQL function, use a `CASE` expression instead of `IF`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test2() RETURNS integer LANGUAGE sql 
AS $$ SELECT CASE WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END; $$;
```

(Note, I haven't bothered to format these readably. Don't write functions all in one line like this in real code.)